# Sql Query to find Temp tables in DB

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please suggest me a query to find temp database tables.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/jnadal/archive/2006/02/24/438960.aspx) helps

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
select name from tempdb.sys.tables
```

Answer (score 7):

All temp tables created are stored in the tempdb available on sql server. So run this query in tempdb, you will find available temp tables on the server -

```
select * from sysobjects where "xtype" = 'u'
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: It also works good but Martin's solution is better I feel.Thanks for your time.